# JUnit files not found 

Tags: java, junit

I've added the JUnit jar to my classpath, and it can find and run tests alright using the command window, but when I try and compile a test I know works, it can't seem to find anything to do with JUnit. I get the following error for every test class. Tested it on another computer and it works, but not on mine. Any ideas?

```
EstateAgentTest.java:25: incompatible types
found   : Test
required: java.lang.annotation.Annotation
    @Test public void rentable1() {
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered this problem today...

Turns out calling my class name "Test.java" was a bad idea - it clashes with the @Test line above your test method. To fix:

1. I renamed my class to SomethingElseTest.java, and it prettymuch fixed the issue.
2. Note that my IDE *did* change my "@Test" line above the method to the new classname, but once I changed that back to @Test, everything was ok again.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably a little late for the creator of the post, but for others that encounter the same problem, I had the exact same problem, and solved it with explicitly adding `import org.junit.Test;`, so my imports now look like this:

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

I have no idea why it didn't work with just `import org.junit.*;`.

Comment: Mine was using the `import junit.framework.Test;` instead of the `import org.junit.Test;`, worked perfect after I replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

The machine where it doesn't work seems to have older version of Java without annotations feature.

You can easily test that by entering `java -version` to your command line. It's probably 1.4 or so and you need at least 1.5 for annotations.

Comment: Are you sure? It can run tests already compiled apparently. Like a previously compiled version of the exact same file.

Comment: @Matt: So, you can run already compiled files, but can't compile new ones? Ok, so annotation processed files with JUnit probably produces backward compatible bytecode. The only way to be sure is to see which are Java versions and try.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

Java 1.6...

Comment: @Matt: Ok, I'm out of ideas. :(

Comment: Please check your "javac" version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll make a difference, but I'm used to seeing the @Test annotation above the test method declaration, like this:

```
@Test
public void testSomething()
{
   // 
}
```

My second guess is that there's another class file for Test imported somehow that is not the JUnit annotation.

Comment: Probably not - tabs, spaces, newlines are all whitespace. But, it's worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have `Test` class somewhere around and it was imported. Try this code to be sure you are working with jUnit `Test` annotation:

```
@org.junit.Test 
void testSomething(){
```